# SQL Injection/ Data Sanitisation on Cloud Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, form

I am creating a custom form on a cloud page in Marketing Cloud. This form will have a free text box at the bottom, which runs the risk of SOQL injection. Does anyone have any tips for the best way to sanitise your data that gets submitted on the form so our data is not attacked? Open to any languages, ampscript, ssjs etc.

Comment: Hi Annie-Louise. Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted, for the benefit of the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here are some best practices](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_microsite_landing_page_security_best_practices.htm&type=5), from Salesforce, for building landing pages.

You should start by including following security headers in your Cloud Pages, especially to avoid XSS:

```
<script runat="server">
   Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("Strict-Transport-Security","max-age=200");
   Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("X-XSS-Protection","1; mode=block");
   Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("X-Frame-Options","Deny");
   Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("X-Content-Type-Options","nosniff");
   Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("Referrer-Policy","strict-origin-when-cross-origin");
   Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("Content-Security-Policy","default-src 'self'");
</script>
```

When it comes to form inputs, API integrations, etc. - submitted data is sanitized before it hits the DB.

I will also suggest taking [this Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-security) on MC Security.