# how to secure sfmc cloud pages from external scripts attack?

Tags: marketing-cloud, security, cloudpage, security-review, form

When it comes to the security of the cloupages. How can we prevent the external scripts running on the cloud pages and secure our cloud pages from RXSS attacks on the smart capture form fields on the cloud pages?

Please help me with this!

Thanks
Adam

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293342/sql-injection-data-sanitisation-on-cloud-page

Comment: @RachidMamai When I am using this script on my cloud page, it's damaging the css of my cloud page and whole design it's not working properly. Do you know how can I prevent this?

Comment: if you are pulling in CSS from external source, this script will prevent that.
so you could host your CSS inside SFMC as code snippet / CSS and use that URL instead. Alternatively, you'd have to make an exclusion in the Content-Security-Policy.
`Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("Content-Security-Policy","default-src 'self'");`

Comment: @JonasLamberty Do you know how can I make an exclusion in the content-security-policy for cloud pages in SFMC?

Comment: @AdamCoder Did you check my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this as an answer to give more details.

Jonas already gave you the answer, but I'll provide an example:

Let's say you have:

- Google API fonts (fonts.googleapis.com...)
- Javascript hosted in something.jquery.com
- CSS hosted in external domain domain2.com
- CSS hosted internally in SFMC as a code resource
- Favicon hosted in an external domain [www.domain3.com/favicon.ico](http://www.domain3.com/favicon.ico)

You need to add all of these as exclusions like below:

```
Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader(
"Content-Security-Policy", 
     "default-src 'self' *.googleapis.com *.jquery.com *.domain2.com; 
     img-src *.domain3.com");
```

You can check out this page for all CloudPages security best practices:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cp_cloud_pages_security_best_practices.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you @RachidMamai & @JonasLamberty! Let me try this solution.